# TF Tree Shared var

Tags: ros, tf-tree

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, does TF support such a structure

```
GLOBAL -> A  
GLOBAL -> B  
GLOBAL -> C 
M -> A  
M -> B
```

I don't want to setup my tree as M -> GLOBAL -> the rest because then I have to manually compute the transform between GLOBAL and M which is annoying

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239590/tf-tree-shared-var/) by [soulslicer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20426/soulslicer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2016-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, no.

Check out the [tf tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20frame%20(C%2B%2B)).

> tf builds up a tree structure of frames; it does not allow a closed loop in the frame structure. This means that a frame only has one single parent, but it can have multiple children.

---

Originally posted by [Arwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10946/arwen/) with karma: 146 on 2016-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [soulslicer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20426/soulslicer/) on 2016-07-15**:
Does that mean if I want to seutp the above strucutre. I need to manually calculate my own transform and publish it that way?

**Comment by [Arwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10946/arwen/) on 2016-07-18**:
I think if the transform between M and A, B and C is fixed, you have to setup your tf tree like this:
Global -> M -> A
I prefer the fixed global frame at the top.
But if you can't setup this configuration, manually compute and broadcast the transform.